# Windows 10 Live Tiles Disappear when SLI enabled

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, sli

My start menu tiles are invisible after playing a game with SLI enabled. If I disable SLI then everything is fine and the tiles stay there after gaming. Another workaround is to restart or log out / log back in.

The green arrows in the attached screenshot illustrate spots where a live tile is, and it's clickable but not visible.

Using Windows 10 and the latest stable GeForce driver (version 358.50).

Just checking to see if others think it's a driver issue, or a setting misconfigured with SLI, or something else I may be missing. All I did to enable SLI was go into the NVidia control panel and under "Configure SLI, Surround, PhysX" set "SLI configuration" to "Maximize 3D performance".

[image: Invisible Live Tiles]

Comment: The first step is to verify the previous driver release has this problem.

Comment: Happened with every windows 10 version of the driver that I have had, definitely a detail I left out on my post though :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is a driver bug, and worth reporting to NVidia / Microsoft.

Something to do with the fact that when in SLI, each card renders a portion of the screen, so the screen is 'carved up' into smaller pieces to facilitate this.

Within the software layer that determines where to draw live tiles on your screen, something is getting confused.

Without testing DirectX, Windows 10, and the GeForce driver side by side in low level detail, it is difficult to determine the culprit... but personally I would suspect NVidia because SLI's approach of 'partitioning' a functioning display view is the niche technique here.

Microsoft own DirectX, Live Tiles and Windows 10 - they will all play nicely together.

Thankfully, NVidia releases their drivers frequently so if someone reports it (I will leave to you as your screenshots are cool) it will get fixed quickly!!

Comment: I have posted on the NVidia Forums and through support. Will update this thread with any information they provide.